# How to change a namespace in a single query?

Tags: kdb

If I try to switch namespace in-place (say via qcon) to define function exactly in namespace (I want to get[`f][3;0] will give exacly the namespace in which it was defined), I got empy result - it seems like no namespace switching occured:

```
\d .
system"d .ns1"; f1:{x+y}; get[.ns1.f1][3;0]~`
```

but:

```
\d .
system"d .ns1"; // notice the only difference is the newline
f1:{x+y}; get[.ns1.f1][3;0]~`ns1
```

Is it a bug of 3.6 32bit version? or a feature?
If it is a feature, then how to switch to new namespace in a single `qcon` query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A code line is evaluated in the context before the code line is executed. Therefore, f1's definition in the first sample was evaluated in the context before namespace switching occurred.